# Grouping Hexagonal Coordinates into Larger Hexagons

Tags: geometry, tiling

When using a data structure to partition space, a convenient approach is to form a sort of self similar hierarchical grid (I'm not sure of the proper terminology here). For example, a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) recursively subdivides each node into four children of equal size.

While trying to accomplish something similar with hexagons, I've hit a bit of a dead end. I happen to be using an axial coordinate system, with the positive portion of the y-axis arranged to be symmetric about the x-axis.

[image: Hexagon Coordinates]

I'm using an analogous coordinate system to label the groups, but rotated slightly to match their layout.

[image: Group Coordinates]

Everything works as expected with the coordinate system itself; the issue arises when I try to translate between child (hexagon) and parent (group) coordinates. Specifically, I'm having trouble with the following points.

- Given the coordinate for any arbitrary hexagon, I'd like to determine the coordinate of its group.
- Given the coordinate for any arbitrary group, I'd like to determine the coordinate of the hexagon at its origin (ie its equivalent of the (0, 0) position in the (0, 0) group).

Some examples to hopefully clarify things (same axes and grouping as images):

- Hex(0, 2) -> Group(0, 0)
- Hex(0, 3) -> Group(0, 1)
- Hex(5, 2) -> Group(1, 0)
- Hex(4, 6) -> Group(1, 1)
- Group(1, 0) -> Hex(3, 2)
- Group(0, -1) -> Hex(2, -3)

So far the math doesn't seem like it will be very simple, but I'm hoping I've missed something.

Comment: Consider using a coordinate system which is not broken; that might help a little.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sorry, it seems I was wrong to refer to it as axial. I don't know what this system's name is (or if it even has one). I'm pretty sure it does work though, I've been using it successfully for a while now. However, I may end up switching to axial if that's what it takes to get the grouping math working.

Comment: There are very many ways to do this. Which are good depend on what you want

Comment: Also you need 3 axes for your coordinate system of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it looks like your coordinate system is a bit wonky (in an axial system, the cells you labelled in the bottom row of the first picture should be (2, -2) and (4, -2) instead of what you have here.

Once you have the right coordinate system, you can do exactly as you want, although it is a bit tricky.

The basic idea is the same as for squares though: you perform some type of division, and throw away the remainder, and get new coordinates. The complication comes in because your shapes are hexagons, and not parallelograms. I cannot remember the details exactly, but you have to calulate something that is similar to a "remainder", and subtract it from the point before doing a division (which is a matrix division). I made a PDF document that explains this (and a lot more, including the proper coordinate system) some time ago:

http://www.gamelogic.co.za/downloads/HexMath2.pdf

(In the comments a few errors are pointed out; I have corrected those now.)

[image]

Comment: It does seem I was wrong to refer to it as axial, sorry about that. Thanks for the incredibly detailed pdf. I'll see if I can get the described techniques working with the coordinate system I'm currently using, but if not I suppose I'll just have to switch to axial.

Comment: I thought initially you just made a mistake... however if there is some sense to your coordinate system, you should have no problems converting.

Comment: (But slso... I really tried all kinds of different systems... and I really recomend the axial system... everything just becomes 'easy'... using the normal tools of linear algebra to do geometry.)

Comment: It turns out my coordinate system was axial with the *negative* y deflected, not the positive y. Also the perceived downside to "regular" axial was trivial to fix, so I'm just switching. I'm accepting your answer, but if you don't mind I'm intending to edit the relevant mathematical details into it once I get everything working.

Comment: Also, in your pdf I believe you are missing a multiplication by the divisor when you define the mod function in equations 54b and 57b... or I may have fundamentally misunderstood something.

Comment: Ah yes you are right! And yes feel free to add any details to the answer :)